# Paint Can Power Plant {gasification stove, steam turbine, dynamo, batteries}

Tags: electromagnetism, charging, power-engineering, energy-harvesting, power-generation

thanks for stopping, here's a little update, this is not going to happen the way I'd hoped so I'm going to change my tack a little, it was suggested that I pick up an alternator so I'll do that and rip apart my bike for donor parts. I need to lose close to a hundred pounds so, in addition to the paint can set up, I want to get exercise while charging my batteries, I mean camping is one thing, I have no intention of roughing it.

Here's why I'm doing this crazy stuff, this project is part of my Movember campaign [{Link to Sweet Tom Movember page here}](http://mobro.co/sweettom) I'm writing and trying to raise awarness at the same time. I have too many ideas and not enough time, I leave Monday night after karaoke so this seems like the obvious thing to me.

So I will start with a pedal power unit to start with and then refine my paint can power plant while I'm up there {somehow lol} I will try to post some pictures and test results of my output when I have something to tell.

I really want to thank everyone for their input... Did I mention that I want to generate power while walking too? I'm thinking a 3D printed tesla turbine with a bladder system in my shoes but that's a whole other kettle of fish.

Cheers

I'm writing a book and part of my story includes a wilderness retreat on which I'll be embarking quite soon. It all started with a paint can, a couple of bucks from Home Depot, turned into a highly efficient wood stove. I had the idea to fashion some kind of steam jack to charge a cell phone but then I asked myself, how much power can we generate with wood pellets as fuel?

As a starving artist, this project uses as many found parts and workarounds as possible as well as embracing the designs of Nikola Tesla and those he inspired. Currently working on locating a stepper motor to re-purpose into the tesla turbine

The next step is a dynamo, I was thinking of an old hand blender motor that I have kicking around but I need your collective knowledge to get from there to batteries.

I also saw this today and wondered if it was possible to incorporate this design:[image]
I'm not sure if that's practical or possible given the time and money constraint.

I also need advice on how to control the charge and dump the input once the batteries are full. I was thinking it would be cool to have a Tesla coil to dump to power to... not sure if I could do it safely in the woods.

I hope I can find the knowledge I need, I wish I had more tile to get it ready.

Live, love and stay Wild my friends

Comment: I have a friend who has been living off the grid in NZ for 15 yrs or more using amazing engineering to sheer wood into automated chipper and runs his truck off this fuel and everything else.  check youtube  he has built the chipper, solar/wind power compressors and engines all off (away from grid. ( not same as "offline" which actually means on the grid)

Comment: Please don't request off-site responses. Responses should be made  as answers below so they can be shared with future readers.

Comment: You are welcome to share your contact info on your user page (click your user name to get there).

Comment: Also, the site is designed to get answers to specific questions, not to produce general discussion. For example, where you say "I was thinking of an old hand blender motor that I have kicking around but I need your collective knowledge to get from there to batteries.", you would get a better response if you formulate a specific question about this issue and post it alone as its own question.

Comment: There is a massive community of off-the-grid developers of solutions you are seeking, but not here in general.

Comment: Automotive alternators are great sources of variable speed voltage regulated chargers driven by steam engines and 1~2HP can be bought cheap from junkyards. Look at V-8 or truck alternators. Bigger the better.

Answer (score 1):

The picture does not seem to be linked to the video, but I believe that the skewed rotor thing is something that claims to "increase efficiency." More conventional designs can already exceed 95%. In the video that I saw previously, the claims were pretty vague, but I suspect this is an attempt to exceed 100% efficiency, in other words, create energy from nothing -- impossible.

A permanent magnet DC motor with a commutator is the easiest type to use as a generator. Cars use PM DC motors for various functions such as electric radiator fans, heat/AC fans, windshield wipers etc. Some have gear heads that prevent each access to the motor shaft, but others should be reasonably easy to use. Since you can probably not control the turbine speed very easily, you need an electronic voltage converter that can convert the variable voltage to a constant charger voltage. Rather than dump the power after charging is complete, just turn the charger off.

You need to start by figuring out what kind of turbine you can build and what speed and torque it will produce. Then look for a motor that either matches that directly or can be matched with a simple belt and pulley system. Determine what the voltage range and current capability will be. Then determine what voltage conversion is needed for your loads.

For best results when operating as a generator, the motor speed should be the same as when it is operated as a motor. The voltage produced will be about the same, or proportional to speed if the speed varies. The generating current capability will be about the current the motor required.